Postman status "Invalid header" for post request, FastApi, python
I am building some small scale application with FastAPI and python.
I am trying to add post request to my application but everytime i try to make a post request it shows invalid header with 400 status (bad request).
See the code below-
Python + fastApi:
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    username: str

    @router.post("/create_user/")
    def create_user(user_data: UserCreate):
        return {
            "msg": "Data received successfully",
            "user_id": user_data.user_id,
            "username": user_data.username,
        }

    app.include_router(router, prefix="/mytest")

Postman request:

I am using daphne to as a server to run fastApi + myapplication. something like- daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 app.main:app (i tried uvicorn too,getting same error with uvicorn)
Strange- If i run this same code with creating just uvicorn instance something like-
Main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = APIRouter()


class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    username: str


@app.post("/create_user/")
async def create_user(user_data: UserCreate):
    user_id = user_data.user_id
    username = user_data.username
    return {
        "msg": "we got data succesfully",
        "user_id": user_id,
        "username": username,
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

The above code executes without any error/exception, python -u main.py
What am i missing?

I am using cors with fastapi

you have defined your route and included router inside you model, that is causing the issue, if you move them outside it should work fine. I doubt how did that code even run in the first place :D
main.py - uvicorn
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    username: str

@router.post("/create_user/")
def create_user(user_data: UserCreate):
    return {
        "msg": "Data received successfully",
        "user_id": user_data.user_id,
        "username": user_data.username,
    }

app.include_router(router, prefix="/mytest")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
    

evidence

main.py - daphne
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    username: str

@router.post("/create_user/")
def create_user(user_data: UserCreate):
    return {
        "msg": "Data received successfully",
        "user_id": user_data.user_id,
        "username": user_data.username,
    }

app.include_router(router, prefix="/mytest")

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     import uvicorn
#     uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

run with:
daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 main:app



No that wont work. Code is fine. You can also try it on your machine.

should i paste my output ?? just a sec

Yes, Please!...

let me change to daphne as well

So this working fine. Post-request and you received reply

Strange! This is some Houdini stuff!...

it did not work for you??
